# How to show percentage progress bar while submit multiple data

Tags: php, ajax, progress-bar, form-submit

How can I add a progress bar with the percentage when submitting multiple data with HTML form by using PHP Ajax.

Comment: 1/ Create the progress bar : one container + one div inside that will represent the progress, 2/ After you submit data calcul the % of data the user has sent and change the width of the progress bar. Eg. 10 questions, user send data for 5 questions -> progress bar is 50%.

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on("change", function() {
    var size = $("input:checked").length;
    var progress = size * 10 + "%";
    
    $(".progress").css("width", progress);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.progress {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>

<form>
<div class="block">
  <input id="one"   name="one"   type="checkbox"><label for="one">One</label></div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="two"   name="two"   type="checkbox"><label for="two">Two</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="three" name="three" type="checkbox"><label for="three">Three</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="four"  name="four"  type="checkbox"><label for="four">Four</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="five"  name="five"  type="checkbox"><label for="five">Five</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="six"   name="six"   type="checkbox"><label for="six">Six</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="seven" name="seven" type="checkbox"><label for="seven">Seven</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="eight" name="eight" type="checkbox"><label for="eight">Eight</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="nine"  name="nine"  type="checkbox"><label for="nine">Nine</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input id="ten"   name="ten"   type="checkbox"><label for="ten">Ten</label>
</div>
</form>
```

For your case :

- replace each checkbox by one of your form
- replace the jQuery trigger by "on submit" and then send the data using Ajax
- in your php (where your send the Ajax data) calcul the % of question user has send
- in your Ajax success part : change the progress bar width according to the % of data

Is it clear enought? Hope it help, but can't help you more since you provide no code !